# How to convert "www.xyx.com/index.php?great=find" to "www.xyz.com" only?

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I am really having trouble understanding this. I used this code first.

```
<script>
if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
    window.history.pushState({}, 'Hide', '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>');
}
```

But then, only the GET parameter (in this case, "great=find") is getting hidden. But the main page is showing "xyz.com/index.php" instead of "xyz.com" only(like it used to show earlier).

How can I solve this? Please provide detailed information if you suggest using .htaccess.

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?great=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R,L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules that can conflict with this on ?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest would be:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```